# Unexpected behavior from masking numpy array with boolean mask

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array of shape `(224,224,160)` and a boolean mask of the same shape.

I mask the array with the mask as such:

```
new = arr[mask]
```

I expect new.shape to be `224*224*160 = (8028160,)`

Printing new.shape actually gives `(1300587,)`

Can anyone tell me where this number is coming from?

Comment: What is `np.sum(mask)`, the number of True/1 values in the mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you index an array with a mask, you get a flattened (i.e. shape = `(N,)`) array containing only the values that the mask allows.

If you're looking for a more pandas-style mask, where values that fail to match the mask are replaced, use `np.where`:

```
np.where(mask, a, np.nan)
```

That will replace values where `mask == False` with `np.nan`, and the shape of the returned array will be identical to that of the original array and the mask.

As [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72510099/unexpected-behavior-from-masking-numpy-array-with-boolean-mask#comment128089653_72510099), the `new.shape` number `1300587` is the number of `True` values in your `mask`.  You should get the same number by running `sum(mask)`.